How to open a new PAGE in Tkinter?
I need to open a new page in Tkinter, but not a new tab. I just need the same tab to change into something different, without opening a new tab
class App(customtkinter.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.title("Test")
        self.geometry(f"{800}x{600}")
        self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure((2, 3), weight=0)
        self.grid_rowconfigure((0, 1, 2), weight=1)
        self.sidebar_frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(self, width=140, corner_radius=0)
        self.sidebar_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=4, sticky="nsew")
        self.sidebar_frame.grid_rowconfigure(4, weight=1)
        self.logo_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self.sidebar_frame, text="test", font=customtkinter.CTkFont(size=20, weight="bold"))
        self.logo_label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=(20, 10))
        
        self.sidebar_button_1 = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.sidebar_frame, command=self.sidebar_button_event_sim, text="test1")
        self.sidebar_button_1.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)
        
        self.sidebar_button_2 = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.sidebar_frame, command=self.sidebar_button_event_data, text="t2")
        self.sidebar_button_2.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)
        
        self.sidebar_button_3 = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.sidebar_frame, command=self.sidebar_button_event_live, text="t3")
        self.sidebar_button_3.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)

    def sidebar_button_event_sim(self):
        print("Test1")
        
    def sidebar_button_event_data(self):
        print("t2")
        
    def sidebar_button_event_live(self):
        print("t3")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()


All other solutions I've seen involve opening new tabs, which is not what I need. I need to be able to add something to the buttons on the left hand side of the actual program that, when the buttons are clicked, allow me to move onto a new page (Not tab)

You need to write another function.

It is not clear what you want.  What do you mean by tab or page?


I need to open a new page in Tkinter, but not a new tab. I just need
the same tab to change into something different, without opening a new
tab

The problem can be fixed.

Create new instantiate class ToplevelWindow.
Add attribute self.toplevel_window = None inside -init_ method.
Write a code inside sidebar_button_event_sim() function.

Snippet:
class ToplevelWindow(customtkinter.CTkToplevel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.geometry("400x300")
        :
        :
        :


        self.toplevel_window = None

    def sidebar_button_event_sim(self):
        if self.toplevel_window is None or not self.toplevel_window.winfo_exists():
            self.toplevel_window = ToplevelWindow(self)  # create window if its None or destroyed
        else:
            self.toplevel_window.focus()  # if window exists focus it

Screenshot:

Screenshot for Toplevel window:

